# (404 Not Found) loading http://localhost:4200/angular2-datatable/datatable

Tags: angular, datatable

I am trying to make a sortable table using [this](https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular2-datatable). I have followed the instructions and it seems that, i have installed the `angular2-datatable/datatable` correctly.
But in the run time it complains that:

```
 GET http://localhost:4200/angular2-datatable/datatable 404 (Not Found)
```

It comes from the line:

```
import {DataTableDirectives} from 'angular2-datatable/datatable';
```

But i checked the **node_module** package and i have `angular2-datatable/datatable` there.
So it seems that angular in the runtime looks in the wrong path.
How can i fix it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Update **angular2-datatable** in your **systemjs.config.js** like this-

```
// map tells the System loader where to look for things
var map = {
    'src':                        'build', // 'dist',
    'rxjs':                       'node_modules/rxjs',
    '@angular':                   'node_modules/@angular',
    'angular2-datatable':         'node_modules/angular2-datatable',
    'lodash':                     'node_modules/lodash/lodash.js',
};

// packages tells the System loader how to load when no filename and/or no extension
var packages = {
    'src':                        { main: 'main.js',  defaultExtension: 'js' },
    'rxjs':                       { defaultExtension: 'js' },
    'angular2-datatable':         { defaultExtension: 'js' },
    'lodash':                     { defaultExtension: 'js' },
};
```

See if this helps.

Comment: This is the Solution @Salman. I was also getting the same error. By including the following data in systemjs.config i was able to solve the problem.