# 404 not found while loading angular2-datatable

Tags: angular, typescript

I add `angular2-datable` library, but I get 404 Not Found while loading library files such as:

- node_modules\angular2-datatable\lib\BootstrapPaginator
- node_modules\angular2-datatable\lib\DataTable
- node_modules\angular2-datatable\lib\DataTableModule
- node_modules\angular2-datatable\lib\DefaultSorter
- node_modules\angular2-datatable\lib\Paginator

I fix my `systemjs.config.js` like [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39318683/404-not-found-loading-http-localhost4200-angular2-datatable-datatable), but it still not works:

```
map: {
   ...
  'lodash': 'npm:lodash/lodash.js',
  'angular2-datatable':'npm:angular2-datatable/index.js'
},
packages: {
   ...
'lodash': {
        defaultExtension: 'js'
},
 'angular2-datatable': {
        defaultExtension: 'js'
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The correct `system.config.js` is like this:

```
map: {
  ...
  'lodash': 'npm:lodash/lodash.js',
  'angular2-datatable':'npm:angular2-datatable'
},
packages: {
   ...
  'lodash': {
    defaultExtension: 'js'
  },
  'angular2-datatable': {
    main: './index.js',
    defaultExtension: 'js'
  }
}
```

- `'angular2-datatable':'npm:angular2-datatable/index.js'` - **not works** for mine
- `'angular2-datatable':'npm:angular2-datatable'` and `main: ./index.js` - **works**